# Plone: How to change ownership of an archetype content?

Tags: python, plone, archetypes

I have contents that needs to change its ownership. By default the owner of the content type is admin, from code `obj.getOwner()` but the Creator of the content type is not admin, e.g. someuser@samplemail.com.

I have followed this link: http://developer.plone.org/content/ownership.html and created a view method for the content type. The following is my code snippet:

```
def change_owner(self):
    membership = getToolByName(self.context,'portal_membership')
    path='/'.join(self.context.getPhysicalPath())
    brains=self.portal_catalog.searchResults(path={'query':path,'depth':0})
    for brain in brains:
        creator = brain.Creator
        crtor_obj = membership.getMemberById(crtor1).getUser()
        brain.getObject().setCreators(creator,)
        brain.getObject().changeOwnership(crtor_obj)
        brain.getObject().reindexObjectSecurity()
    return
```

It seems that my code didn't change the ownership of the content. The owner is still admin and the Creator is still the original Creator. Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see three problems:

- You call `getObject()` repeatedly. That is a relatively expensive operation, cache the result in a local variable instead:

  ```
  obj = brain.getObject()
  ```
- You called `setCreators()` with one argument, not a list:

  ```
  obj.setCreators([creator])
  ```
- You don't change the `Owner` role:

  ```
  roles = list(obj.get_local_roles_for_userid(crtor_obj))
  if 'Owner' not in roles:
      roles.append('Owner')
      obj.manage_setLocalRoles(crtor_obj, roles)
  ```

There is a [`plone.app.changeownership` product](http://plone.org/products/plone.app.changeownership) that takes care of all these details for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was now able to change the ownership of the content.

Answer (score 3):

did you have a look at [plone.app.changeownership](http://plone.org/products/plone.app.changeownership) ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a helper function `changeOwnershipOf(self, object, userid, recursive=0, REQUEST=None)` in `plone_utils` that does all these things for you.

(Findable via the underexposed `change_ownership` form.)